# Conditional Formatting a Date Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am completely all new to this.

I have a simple SharePoint list recording training.

What coding would I need to write in, to achieve the following:

- blank fields - color red
- anything else with a date in goes green.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirements, you have to use the **Column formatting** in SharePoint. Follow steps given [here in official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#get-started-with-column-formatting) to open column formatting settings & add below JSON code.

You can use simple JSON like below to format your date columns:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', 'sp-field-severity--good')"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

See other ways to check if date column is empty at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

---

**Official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use column formatting to meet your needs in SharePoint Online.

**Please following steps:**

1.Go to the list as a site admin

2.Select the "Date and time" column >> **Column settings** >> **Format this column**

[image]

3.On the Format Column windows, click on "**Advanced mode**" link

[image]

4.Please use the below JSON code

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, 'sp-field-severity--blocked','sp-field-severity--good')"
  }
}
```

[image]

5.Click "**Save**"

[image]

Comment: Is there any difference in JSON provided in my answer & your answer?